# Twilio SIP to SIP calls from ATA

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have setup a SIP domain, where I have registered two SIP devices (alice, bob). I want those devices to be able to call each other. One of the devices is a ATA connected to a phone, so dialing a SIP address (user@domain.sip.us1.twilio.com) on the user terminal is no an option.

- What would be the architecture to use to enable one user to call the other one (like dialing an extension number on a PBX). The call needs to be initiated on the terminal/end-point, not on a website (click to call).
- Where should I code the trigger to intercept the event of a SIP device dial a number, which I then can connect to the other device? Is there something similar to a dialplan that can be implemented in TwiML?

I have only one DID inbound number and would prefer not to have another number only for that role.

I am using node, by any language works. Ideally I would like this to be implemented as serverless within Twilio.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To close the loop, this was [answered in the Twilio community forum](https://community.twilio.com/community/discussion/530/sip-to-sip-calls). TL;DR: follow [this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound).

Comment: Thanks Phil - for those facing similar issues, this is the recipe I had to use twilio 'services' instead of functions.

  // const dial = twiml.dial();
  // dial.sip({timeLimit: 120},'sipaddress@domain.sip.twilio.com')